# How do I set the image in position static so that it won't overflow?

Tags: php, html, css

[here is the image about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7by.png)

Since Im just learn web development for 1 month only, so idk whether this is possible or not...

```
.TEST1123{
  position: static;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Position has nothing to do with overflow.

Comment: by setting the image width to 100%;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all position has nothing to do with overflow.

you can set `width:100%; height:100%;` on your image.

In this way

```
   .TEST1123{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
    }
```

Comment: yeah...It's my pleasure...don't forget to vote ;)

Comment: Okayy, I would vote it if I reach 15 reputation.

Comment: Sorry bro I forgot that. It's ok :)